# Trouble with new RubyMotion and Joybox

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymotion

Is anyone having trouble with the updated rubymotion with joybox?  I just updated rubymotion this morning and my app broke immediately... Here is my error.

```
Inheriting from Motion::Project::Command' has been deprecated, inherit fromMotion::Command' instead.
```

Not sure if that is why it's breaking... But I need to figure this out.  I've tried rolling back versions, and can't find a version that works.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, installed Joybox this morning, ruined my RubyMotion install so bad I can't even reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up removing the joybox gem, but then my RubyMotion was throwing crazy errors on rake.

I fixed it by removing ~/Library/RubyMotion/templates/joybox-*.rb.

Hope that helps. I don't think Joybox is stable with latest RM.

Comment: It's actually symbolic links and not .rb files, in the template directory. Also need to remove the files in the command folder. ~/Library/RubyMotion/command

Comment: FYI - it's ~/Library/RubyMotion/template/joybox-*.rb ;) Thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score -1):

One solution is post [here](https://github.com/rubymotion/Joybox/issues/70). Revert to RM 2.20 :

```
sudo motion update --cache-version=2.20
```

then in your Rakefile, replace :

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
```

by

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion2.20/lib")
```

Finally, reinstall joybox gem :

```
sudo gem install joybox
```

And all should be ok.